# Either $H \triangleleft G$ or exist a conjugated subgroup $H^g \subseteq N_G (H)$, in which $g \in G$, with $H^g \neq H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a $p-$group. If $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, prove that either $H \triangleleft G$ or exist a conjugated subgroup $H^g \subseteq N_G (H)$, in which $g \in G$, with $H^g \neq H$.

In my opinion, to solve this problem we must use the formula of orbit
$$|\mathcal{O} (x)| = |G : S_G (x)|$$

Could you give me some hint to solve this problem! Thank all!

Comment: What do you mean " $ H $ be a normal subgroup of $ G $ then either $ H\triangleleft G $   "?

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: I don't think you want to assume that $H$ is a *normal* subgroup of $G$.  I think you just want to assume $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Minh Well you did not.

Comment: @RobertShore You right! I see it

Comment: If $H$ is not normal in $G$ then choose any $g \in N_G(N_G(H)) \setminus N_G(H)$.

Comment: I didn't understand. We are discussing about $H$.

Answer (score 2):

I will make my comment into an answer. If $H$ is not normal in $G$, then $N_G(H) \ne G$ and so, by a standard property of $p$-groups, $N_G(H)$ is properly contained in its normalizer $N_G(N_G(H))$.

Now choose any $g \in N_G(N_G(H)) \setminus N_G(H)$, and we have $H^g \le N_G(H)$ with $H^g \ne H$.

Comment: Is $N_G(N_G (H)) \neq \emptyset$??? If  $N_G(N_G (H)) = \emptyset$ we can't choose $g \in  N_G(N_G (H)) \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: No subgroup of any group can be the empty set.

Comment: $N_G(N_G (H))$ is a subgroup of $G$, but is  $N_G(N_G (H)) \setminus N_G (H)$ be a subgroup of $G$???

Comment: No, I never said it was. It could not possibly be a subgroup because it does not contain the identity element.  I said that it is nonempty.

Comment: Why  $N_G(N_G (H))$ is nonempty? I see some cases  $N_G(N_G (H)) = N_G (H)$, and in that cases,  $N_G(N_G (H)) \setminus N_G (H) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Please read what I write. As I said in the first paragraph, it is nonempty because $G$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: @Minh And the property holds even in nilpotent groups: "normalizers grow" principle as it is called.